# How to write comma separated value in single quote in java script?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic list of emails which are separated by comma, and I want to put all in single comma
In example:

```
(a@zyz.com,b@xyz.com,c@xyz.com,d@xyz.com) to ('a@zyz.com','b@xyz.com','c@xyz.com','d@xyz.com')
```

I tried to resolve it, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want to enclose emails with single quotes, you can split on `,` and then `Array.map` and then `Array.join`

```
var str = "a@zyz.com,b@xyz.com,c@xyz.com,d@xyz.com";
str = str.split(",").map(function(str){
    return "'" + str + "'"; // add quotes
}).join(",") // join the array by a comma
```

Comment: @JackBond glad to have saved you time :)

Answer (score 1):

use split method of javascript.

E.g.

```
  var str = "a@zyz.com,b@xyz.com,c@xyz.com,d@xyz.com";
    var res = str.split(',');
```